Circular Import and Initialization Error when importing matplotlib with numpy
I have already attempted uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib
I'm encountering the following errors when I attempt to import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

Returns:
ImportError: cannot import name 'VisibleDeprecationWarning' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import)

Troubleshooted by commenting out numpy and attempting matplotlib.pyplot
This is the only other error I received.
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot

Returns:
ImportError: initialization failed

Thank you for your time.

Have you named the python file something that is conflicting with the packages?

Post the entire error message which may give additional hints to the problem. When you run a script, python will put that script's directory in the python path and any .py file in that path will shadow like-named files in the python installation. This error usually happens because you have a script in your directory with the same name as something numpy is importing. Or you are accidentally reimporting your own script. You could create a fresh subdirectory somewhere, add a script called "test.py" that just does import numpy to see if it works.

This can result from a namespace collision such as naming the file you are executing numpy.py. To fix this, change the name of the script you are executing.

The file I'm editing in is titled test.py. Is that what you mean?

@HowCanDoesCK try changing that file name to something that definitely won't be used by a package and see if it works.

this didn't work I appreciate your help though
